# Clicking on the form causes 'Unable to cast object of type '<Namespace.FormName>' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

Tags: vb.net, minesweeper

I am making a version of the Microsoft game 'Minesweeper'. I make the buttons and labels programmatically  and add two handlers for the buttons and one handler for the labels as follows.

```
AddHandler Newbtn.MouseDown, AddressOf Button_MouseDown
AddHandler Newbtn.MouseUp, AddressOf Button_MouseUp
AddHandler Newlbl.MouseDown, AddressOf Label_MouseDown
```

then I have three procedures:

```
Private Sub Button_MouseUp(sender As Button, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
 Private Sub Button_MouseDown(sender As Button, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
Private Sub Label_MouseDown(sender As Label, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
```

Everything works fine until I click outside of the grid of buttons on the form itself, when I get a 'invalidcastexception'. VS2015 goes into a break state. At the top it says:

"Your Application has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code(typically system or framework code)."

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Mines.MineSweeperPJS' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.

Mines is the Namespace.
MineSweeperPJS is the form.

Any suggestions as to the cause of this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part of your event handlers

```
..... Handles Me.MouseUp
             ^^^
```

this means that every mouseup, or mousedown event on your form (`Me`) are passed to the event handler specified.
I think that you have written this event handler manually changing the parameter `sender` from Object to Button because if you let the Form Designer use its own template you end up with something like this

```
Private Sub Button_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Newbtn.MouseUp
```

When the form engine calls these event handlers, in response to a Form mousedown or mouseup it passes the reference to the Form itself (Me) and not the reference to a Button. And this is the reason of the invalid cast.

You could remove the `...Handles Me.MouseUp` because you have already set up the event handlers using the AddHandler and also restore the `sender` parameter to be `As Object`

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I removed the handles and it all works perfectly. My coding education mostly comes from google where I search for the things I don't know :) So the procedure headers were copy pasted from here most likely. I really appreciate sites like this and the help their participants offer. Pete.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, you're right I did change the sender to button and label. One of my many attempts to try and get it to work. I also tried many variations on the handles but never tried removing then, ha :)